# How to choose best algorithm for sorting

Tags: algorithm, sorting, automation

I'm newbie here.

I am currently trying to solve the problem regarding the sorting algorithm.
I will outline the situation:

we have 60 items. Variables of type A and B are written to these items. Variables A and B are stored randomly. Variables A and B have another parameter X, which indicates their material. (material may change during storage). Items are then taken one by one to another item with 10 elements, where we try to achieve the storage of 2 or 3 of the same types of variables A or B from the same material on one element. After saving the required number of variables with the same properties, they are subsequently removed from this item.

I tried to describe it as simply as possible, but maybe I should have described it with a real example.

It can be imagined as a warehouse that has 10 elements and takes from a conveyor that has a capacity of 60 elements. As soon as the warehouse has the same type of goods of the same material on one element, it dispatches the goods and releases its position.

So I want to remove the elements from the conveyor as efficiently as possible and sort them in stock according to requirements.

It occurred to me to sort by case for all options.

Thank you for all your ideas and comments. If it's not very clear, then I apologize and try to explain it differently. :)

Comment: Instead of describing the data, present the data (for example in JSON format).

Comment: conveyorPos1 = {name:"A", material:"X"};                                                        conveyorPos2 = {name:"B", material:"X"};   ...                                                                                                                                                                                                                    conveyorPos60 = {name:"B", material:"X"}; 60 elements on the conveyor in this way (data) And then these elements are removed and sorted according to the requirements of what I grabbed above.

Comment: Do you know about arrays?

Comment: Please edit your question, and add this information. Also give expected output of the algorithm, for the given sample input data.

Comment: Why do you need sorting? To me it sounds like you could just take a HashMap with the material (or maybe material and name) as key and the amount as value.